# Firestore will not save words with accents?

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to move data to Firestore from a MySQL table encoded as utf-8 (specifically, utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci). I'm using Golang's Firestore libraries along with sqlx. Most or every word that has accent characters fails, e.g., müller, évident, etc. The error returned is as follows:

> rpc error: code = Internal desc = grpc: error while marshaling: proto:
>   field "google.firestore.v1.Value.ValueType" contains invalid UTF-8

I can enter the accent characters into Firestore manually using the browser-based interface, so I'm guessing the issue lies with the Golang library. Is there any workaround that would preserve the accent characters?

Comment: Firestore is definitely able to save accented characters, so likely something is going wrong somewhere along the way. Can you update your question to include the minimum, standalone code that is needed to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I went looking for a way to provide the standalone code, only to discover that a word tokenization function I had written was mangling accented characters. Converting the strings to runes took care of the problem.

Comment: @Brent If you solved the problem, then you could answer your own question with the solution.

Comment: Great to hear that you found the problem. That's one of the magic side-effect of [creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): you often find the problem while doing so. Can you (as Doug also asked) post your solution as an answer? That way others can possibly benefit from your experience. Otherwise, I'll vote to close this question as a temporal problem/typo.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to my issue was unrelated to Firestore and libraries I was using, but instead was a problem in a word-tokenization function I had written. The tokenization was mangling accented characters into bad UTF-8, so converting them to runes before tokenization solved the issue.